# when i run from xcode i get the following failed to emit precompiled header, version xcode Version 14.2 (14C18)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I have the file project-Bridging-Header.h and when I run in xcode it shows:
failed to emit precompiled header '/Applications/proyectos/javascript/react-native/project/project/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/project-Bridging-Header-swift_2GFW1TLW4O3RM-clang_1HCJH2Z17CQX3.pch' for bridging header '/Applications/proyectos/javascript/react-native/project/project/ios/project-Bridging-Header.h'

My file has project-Bridging-Header.h:

```
#import "React/RCTBridge.h"
#import "React/RCTViewManager.h"
#import "React/RCTUIManager.h"
#import "React/UIView+React.h"
#import "React/RCTBridgeModule.h"
#import "React/RCTEventDispatcher.h"
#import "React/RCTEventEmitter.h"
#import "React/RCTFont.h"
```